# Struts2 displaytag dynamic link show same rows value

Tags: javascript, struts2

I need some help where I can't get solution even do research.

```
<display:column property="productName" title="Product Name" href="javascript:viewProd('${productList.productID}')" style="width:20%"/>
```

I want to pass the productID to javascript to run some function but it get the first record of productID and other rows also get the first records.

Please guide me.

Comment: What is the action code?!

Answer (score 0):

Add `uid="row"`attribute to the `display:table` tag. Then you can use it in the column

```
<display:column property="productName" title="Product Name" href="javascript:viewProd('${row.productID}')" style="width:20%"/>
```

Comment: it still get the product id of the first record.

Comment: the row variable is used to get the row object that could be any record in the table.